# Como realizar requisição SOAP com e sem proxy

Tags: php, web-service, soap

Boa tarde pessoal,

**Cenário**:

"A empresa onde trabalho possui proxy. Porém vez ou outra tem-se a necessidade de desabilitá-lo e definir as configurações de IPv4 manualmente."

Sendo assim, consigo consumir o SoapClient para a primeira situação com os seguintes parâmetros:

```
$comProxy = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'login'        => $user,
    'password'     => $pass,
    'proxy_host'     => \Config::$hostProxy,
    'proxy_port'     => \Config::$portProxy,
    'proxy_login'    => \Config::$userProxy,
    'proxy_password' => \Config::$passProxy
);
```

Já na segunda situação, o seguintes parâmetros são suficientes:

```
$semProxy = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'login'        => $user,
    'password'     => $pass
);
```

**Problema**:

Toda vez que tem-se a necessidade de definir as configurações de IP manualmente, tenho que mudar os parâmetros manualmente para que a requisição seja bem sucedida.

O seguinte erro é causado quando defino as configurações de IP manualmente utilizando os parâmetros do array **$comProxy**:

> Mensagem: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://crago.cra21.com.br/crago/xml/protestos.php?wsdl' : failed to
>   load external entity
>   "http://crago.cra21.com.br/crago/xml/protestos.php?wsdl"

**Tentativa**:

Utilização de um manipulador de erros personalizado, para quando SoapClient lançar a exceção citada (SOAP-ERROR), tentar fazer uma nova requisição com os parâmetros do array $semProxy. Porém sem sucesso, pois perco o contexto da execução, além da mesma forçar a interrupção do script.

**Pergunta**:

O que fazer para que o SoapClient reconheça as configurações de proxy e utilize os parâmetros corretos para cada situação?

Comment: Ja verificou se seu servidor de hospedagem aceita solicitações remotas ?

Comment: Consigo fazer solicitações tanto com e sem proxy, porém tenho que alterar os parâmetros de configuração do SoapClient manualmente sempre que há essa alteração.

Comment: Então... o servidor aceita solicitação remota. vc pode editar sua pergunta enviando o restante do código que faz essa conexão e solicitação ? e o momento em que você acredita que ocorre o erro? tá usando outra linguagem?, javascript por exemplo para fazer essa requisicao? Se sim, me envie o evento que faz isso.

Comment: Estou utilizando PHP e o trecho de código é simplesmente um `$this->wsdl = new SoapClient($url, $options);` que  está dentro de um bloco **try catch**. Sendo que, `$options` é o array $comProxy ou $semProxy. Quero que, por exemplo, mesmo utilizando $comProxy e definindo as configurações de IP manualmente na placa de rede e/ou navegador, eu consiga fazer as requisições.